# Gentium font with cyrillic

Tags: fonts, xetex, cyrillic

There is a way, to use Gentium font with cyrillic text?

I tried so:

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec} % loaded by polyglossia, but included here for transparency 
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{russian} 
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\russianfont[Script=Cyrillic,]{Gentium}


\begin{document}
    Test, \textbf{test} 

    Тест, \textbf{тест}
\end{document}
```

but I have no bold in this case:

[image]

Another try:

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec} % loaded by polyglossia, but included here for transparency 
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{russian} 
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\russianfont[Script=Cyrillic,BoldFont={Gentium Basic Bold}]{Gentium}


\begin{document}
    Test, \textbf{test} 

    Тест, \textbf{тест}
\end{document}
```

So now I have bold version of font, but cyrillc don't work:

[image]

Comment: Maybe Gentium does not have bold cyrillic. If you try another font and it works, it surely is an issue with Gentium. Use another font instead, if you really need bold faces.

Answer (score 6):

The Gentium font, as currently distributed, has no boldface version. The Gentium Basic font has no Cyrillic, so you're stuck.

You can fake the boldface, though.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec} % loaded by polyglossia, but included here for transparency
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\russianfont[
  Script=Cyrillic,
  BoldFont={Gentium},
  BoldFeatures={FakeBold=4},
]{Gentium}


\begin{document}
    Test, \textbf{test}

    Тест, \textbf{тест}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For a very limited usage of boldface this may be regarded as acceptable.

Comment: Is it possible to make something like: `if(containsCyrlillicCharacters()) use Gentium with FakeBold; else use normal Gentium` in `textbf()` definition?

Comment: @Stas Yes, if you mark the passages in English with `\foreignlanguage` or similar function.